# Not playing media issue

Tags: 18.04, sound, media

I've installed Ubuntu 1 week ago and it was working fine so far. This is my computer at work and I never used Ubuntu before.
Today, after logging in, I noticed double sign-in into my profile, Chrome signed out from my Google account, media stopped playing (i.e. Spotify app, any kind of in-browser sounds or videos etc.), mic isn't working and terminal won't open (only change of region helps and it resets after restart so I have to do it every time). There might be more. What could've caused these issues? I have no clue and I have tried a lot. Does anyone know how to fix it? I really don't want to re-install my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by Google Chrome remote desktop application for Ubuntu. Removing it fixes all those issues.